# How to add Service archive generator and code generator plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache, plugins, apache-axis

I have downloaded Service  archive and code generator wizard plugin for Eclipse (From http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/index.html). I am following steps mentioned here http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/plugin-installation.html.
I extracted the content of plugin folder into dropin folder but not able to see Service archive or code generator wizard.I tried copying all content into Plugin folder but no luck.
How can we add this two plugins ?

**PS:** I am using Eclipse Helios.

~Ajinkya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the latest version (1.6.1) of the plugins

There's an open apache issue for a problem loading the plugin
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5145

Altho this is for Indigo it might be the same problem you're having (just check)
If that's the case I'd either wait for a fix or try an older version of the plugins (I'm using 1.5.4 which works just fine)

Comment: I was having the same issue,had tried 1.5.2 and 1.7.0 . But 1.5.4 is working fine